# Windows Forwarded Event Logs Watcher works only the first time

Tags: c#, console-application, event-log

After subscribing the watcher to the Event Log it works, but just on the first update. Further updates are not working, they are just ignored.

```
      static readonly HttpClient client = new();
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventLogWatcher watcher = null;
        try
        {
            EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("ForwardedEvents", PathType.LogName);
            watcher = new EventLogWatcher(eventsQuery);
            watcher.EventRecordWritten +=new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(handlerExplorerLaunch);
            watcher.Enabled = true;

        }
        catch (EventLogReadingException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error reading the log: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void consoleWriteEvent(Evento evento)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(evento.toString());
            EscribirSeparador();
            
    }
    
    static Evento crearEvento(EventRecord eventdetail)
    {
        try
        {
            Evento evento = new Evento();
            switch (eventdetail.Id)
            {
                case 1074:
                    evento = crearEvento1074(eventdetail);
                    break;
                case 6008:
                    evento = crearEvento6008(eventdetail);
                    break;
                case 4624:
                    evento = crearEvento4624(eventdetail);
                    break;
                case 4634:
                    evento = crearEvento4634(eventdetail);
                    break;
                case 4672:
                    evento = crearEvento4672(eventdetail);
                    break;
            }
            return evento;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught in the event logger!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static void handlerExplorerLaunch(object obj,
        EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg)
    {
        if (arg.EventRecord != null)
        {
            Evento evento = crearEvento(arg.EventRecord);
            if (evento != null  && evento.Usuario != "SYSTEM" )
            {
                consoleWriteEvent(evento);
                sendEvento(client, evento);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The event instance was null.");
        }
    }
    static Evento crearEvento4624(EventRecord eventdetail)
    {
        try{
            return new Evento() { Hora = eventdetail.TimeCreated.Value, Usuario = eventdetail.Properties.Cast<EventProperty>().ElementAt(5).Value.ToString(), Tipo = eventdetail.TaskDisplayName, Ordenador = eventdetail.MachineName, Security =  "TEST" };
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new Evento() { Hora = eventdetail.TimeCreated.Value, Usuario ="No disponible", Tipo = eventdetail.Id.ToString(), Ordenador = eventdetail.MachineName, Security =  "TEST" };

        }
    }
    static Evento crearEvento4634(EventRecord eventdetail)
    {
        try
        {
            return new Evento() { Hora = eventdetail.TimeCreated.Value, Usuario = eventdetail.Properties.Cast<EventProperty>().ElementAt(1).Value.ToString(), Tipo = eventdetail.TaskDisplayName, Ordenador = eventdetail.MachineName, Security =  "TEST" };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Evento() { Hora = eventdetail.TimeCreated.Value, Usuario = "No disponible", Tipo = eventdetail.Id.ToString(), Ordenador = eventdetail.MachineName, Security =  "TEST" };

        }
    }
    static Evento crearEvento4672(EventRecord eventdetail)
    {
        try
        {
            return new Evento() { Hora = eventdetail.TimeCreated.Value, Usuario = eventdetail.Properties.Cast<EventProperty>().ElementAt(1).Value.ToString(), Tipo = eventdetail.TaskDisplayName, Ordenador = eventdetail.MachineName, Security =  "TEST" };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Evento() { Hora = eventdetail.TimeCreated.Value, Usuario = "No disponible", Tipo = eventdetail.Id.ToString(), Ordenador = eventdetail.MachineName, Security =  "TEST" };

        }
    }
    static Evento crearEvento6008(EventRecord eventdetail)
    {
        return new Evento() { Hora = eventdetail.TimeCreated.Value, Usuario = "No disponible", Tipo = eventdetail.Id.ToString(), Ordenador = eventdetail.MachineName,Security =  "TEST" };
    }
    static Evento crearEvento1074(EventRecord eventdetail)
    {
        return new Evento() { Hora = eventdetail.TimeCreated.Value, Usuario = eventdetail.UserId.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString(), Tipo = eventdetail.Properties.Cast<EventProperty>().ElementAt(4).Value.ToString(), Ordenador = eventdetail.MachineName, Security =  "TEST" };

    }
    static void EscribirSeparador() {
        string val = "";
        for (int i  = 0; i<Console.BufferWidth;i++)
        {
            val = val + "-";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
    static async Task sendEvento(HttpClient client, Evento evento)
    {
        try
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(evento);
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://atbrh.azurewebsites.net/api/eventos", data);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught in the api call!");
            Console.WriteLine("During event: " + evento.toString() + " with intended password: " + evento.Security);
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        }
```

I need the watcher to keep looking for events ad infinitum and send them to the API so i can treat them and access them through the API. I think the affected code is

```
watcher = new EventLogWatcher(eventsQuery);
watcher.EventRecordWritten +=new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(handlerExplorerLaunch);
watcher.Enabled = true;
```

But I have no idea why.

EDIT:
Okay so, after some testings I've noticed that `sendEvento(client, evento)` should be `await sendEvento(client, evento)` because it's an async call. The thing is if I make the event handler function (`handlerExplorerLaunch`) async, the EventHandler on   `watcher.EventRecordWritten +=new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(handlerExplorerLaunch);` never triggers. Is there any way to make an event handler with Async callback?

Comment: I'm curious about this conditional : evento != new Evento()  How can that ever be false?

Comment: @Duston ups mb that shouldn't be there, I put that there for some tests... BTW I'm gonna update my question with some things I discovered

Comment: Oh and sorry for the mix of spanish and english on the code, I am currently just prototyping and coding fast.

Comment: And just FYI, if you prefer Spanish, there is https://es.stackoverflow.com/ Stackoverflow en Espa;ol.

Comment: I do use both, thank you @Duston, but SO in english helps me improve my english as well!

Comment: (And that's why I use SO in Spanish.)